# Compare two dict and update one of them

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have two dictionaries like the following:

```
dict1 = 
{'a': [67.0, 24.0, 45.0, 45.0, 45.0, 23.0, 21.0, 45.0],
 'b': [0.9, 0.5, 9.0, 4.5, 54.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'c': [1.0, 5.0, 40.0, 30.0, 20.0, 0.0, 10.0, 50.0],
 'd': [60.0, 80.0, 56.0, 34.0, 78.0, 13.0, 0.0, 70.0]}

dict2 = 
{'a': 0.897,'c': 3.4, 'd': 34.567}
```

I want all the values in `dict1` to be shifted right by value of 1. The keys of `dict1` and `dict2` are compared. If there exist a value for the similar keys in`dict2`, the value is put as the first element in the values of `dict1` (which is a list). If there exist no value in `dict2`, the value the first element is 0.0. For eg:

When the two dictionaries are compared, dict2 contains values for the key `'a'`, `'c'`, `'d'`. So the values for these keys are put as the first element in the value of `dict1` (which is a list) while shifting the other elements of the list to right. The size of the list is maintained. For the keys which do not contain a value in `dict2`, a value of 0.0 is put as the first element in the list as shown below

```
dict1 = 
{'a': [0.897, 67.0, 24.0, 45.0, 45.0, 45.0, 23.0, 21.0],
 'b': [0.0, 0.9, 0.5, 9.0, 4.5, 54.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'c': [3.4, 1.0, 5.0, 40.0, 30.0, 20.0, 0.0, 10.0],
 'd': [34.567, 60.0, 80.0, 56.0, 34.0, 78.0, 13.0, 0.0]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this operation is done repeatedly I suggest you use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects),  the time complexity of appending to the left of deque is `O(1)` (in a list is `O(n)`).

```
from collections import deque

dict1 = {k: deque(v, maxlen=len(v)) for k, v in dict1.items()}

for key, value in dict1.items():
    value.appendleft(dict2.get(key, 0.0))


print(dict1)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': deque([0.897, 67.0, 24.0, 45.0, 45.0, 45.0, 23.0, 21.0], maxlen=8),
 'b': deque([0.0, 0.9, 0.5, 9.0, 4.5, 54.0, 0.0, 0.0], maxlen=8),
 'c': deque([3.4, 1.0, 5.0, 40.0, 30.0, 20.0, 0.0, 10.0], maxlen=8),
 'd': deque([34.567, 60.0, 80.0, 56.0, 34.0, 78.0, 13.0, 0.0], maxlen=8)}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate over `dict1` and if the key exists in `dict2`, insert the value from dict2 into the index `0` of `list` in `dict1` or insert `zero` with the default value with `dict.get`.

```
for k,v in dict1.items():
    dict1[k].pop()                        # removing last element from each 'list` in 'dict1'
    dict1[k].insert(0, dict2.get(k, 0.0)) # insert elelment at 'index=0' from 'dict2' or 'zero' if key doesn't exist in 'dict2'
      
print(dict1)
```

---

```
{
    'a': [0.897, 67.0, 24.0, 45.0, 45.0, 45.0, 23.0, 21.0], 
    'b': [0.0, 0.9, 0.5, 9.0, 4.5, 54.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
    'c': [3.4, 1.0, 5.0, 40.0, 30.0, 20.0, 0.0, 10.0], 
    'd': [34.567, 60.0, 80.0, 56.0, 34.0, 78.0, 13.0, 0.0]
}
```

Comment: I would like to insert a float value i.e 0.0 instead of 0. I believe insert accepts only integer arguments. Is there a workaround?